# Django get id of the selected checkbox on CheckboxSelectMultiple widget in Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, checkbox, multiplechoicefield

I have checkboxes in Django from a form :

```
testrever = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False,widget=forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

I would like to return only the ID (and then the value) of the last selected checkbox on `.change` event only when it's checked (when it's unchecked I don't want anything to happen).

I managed to do so with the following (thanks to this answer) :

[Django How to get value of CheckboxSelectMultiple in Javascript in Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76291806/django-how-to-get-value-of-checkboxselectmultiple-in-javascript-in-template)

```
$('#id_testrever_0').on("change", function() {
    var testrever =[]
    var a = $("#id_email").val();
    if ($('#id_testrever_0').is(':checked')) {
        testrever = $('#id_testrever_0').val();
        $("input[name=email]").val(a + testrever)
    }
})
    $('#id_testrever_1').on("change", function() {
    var testrever =[]
    var a = $("#id_email").val();
    if ($('#id_testrever_1').is(':checked')) {
        testrever = $('#id_testrever_1').val();
        $("input[name=email]").val(a + testrever)
    }
})
```

But I would like to achieve it in a more elegant way to minimise the code lenght and avoid the repetitions.

maybe by using

```
$("input:checkbox[name=testrever]").on("change", function() 

  $("input:checkbox[name=testrever]:checked").each(function()
```

if it's possible.

Comment: I'm not entirely following what you mean with "*returning*". Returning where?

Comment: I simplified the code but the idea is still to be able to copy the value on an input text widget. I'm updating the code for you to understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely convinced I I fully understand what you want. But if you want to append the value of `#id_email` with the value of the checkbox checked, you can use:

```
$('#id_testrever input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        const element = $('#id_email');
        element.val(element.val() + this.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's 100% what i was looking for. Thanks once again